# Asp.NET error screen's HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, stack-trace, httpmodule, global-asax

Guys, what is the name of HttpModule which serves standard Asp.Net error screens with the stack trace? Can I disable this in order to modify response when application error occurs? Or is there another way to modify the response for example in Global.asax or custom HttpModule on Application_Error?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use much better `CustomErrors` section in web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

Comment: I need to modify the response on async postback, not to show custom error page.

Comment: I am still not clear, you can do whatever you want on your error.aspx page. Do you mean whenever error orccurs in your application, you want to show error there itself on same page asynchronously ?